# How to clone form elements with auto incremented id to all elements

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a form under a `<tr id="repeat">`. I want to clone this and append dynamically in another `<tr id="repeat1">` and so on dynamically. Also I need to assign auto incremented id to all form elements too. Apart from pure javascript I can not use any jQuery or any other library.

Here is my HTML

```
<tr id="repeat">
    <td><input type="text" id="fieldName" /></td>
    <td>
        <select name="fieldType" id="fieldType">
            <option value="string">String</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="mandatory" name="mandatory" value="true" /><input type="radio" id="mandatory" name="mandatory" value="false" /></td>
    <td>Delete Button</td>
</tr>
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
var i = 0;

this.view.findById("start").addEventHandler("click", function () {
    var original = document.getElementById('repeat');
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
})
```

Presently I can cloned the form elements in `<tr id="repeated1">` dynamically and so on, but unable to assign auto incremented id to input box and select box. Also unable to assign auto incremented name to the radio buttons dynamically

Comment: Should use `setAttribute` like `youElement.setAttribute('id','yourIncrementId')`

Comment: Thank you very much. This one works for id incremental.  But for still now unable to incremented 'name' of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `Id` or another attribute as you want.

but for your code my solution is using `querySelectorAll` to get element and change it's Id, something like below code, it is tested and works nice:

Based on this HTML design code and JS function:

```js
function MakeElementsWithDifferentId() {
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
             var original = document.getElementById('repeat');
             var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
             clone.id="repeat"+i;
             clone.querySelectorAll('[id="fieldName"]')[0].id ="fieldName"+i; 
             clone.querySelectorAll('[id="fieldType"]')[0].id ="fieldType"+i; 
             clone.querySelectorAll('[id="mandatory"]')[0].id ="mandatory"+i; 
             clone.children[2].children[0].name="mandatoryName"+i; //To change the radio name also
             original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
        }
    }
    MakeElementsWithDifferentId();
```

```html
  <table>
        <tr id="repeat">
            <td><input type="text" id="fieldName" /></td>
            <td>
                <select name="fieldType" id="fieldType">
                    <option value="string">String</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mandatory" name="mandatory" value="true" /> </td>
            <td>Delete Button</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

the `MakeElementsWithDifferentId()` function make 10 batch elements with different Ids.

the [JSFiddle Test](https://jsfiddle.net/kg75h66n/1/)

after run you can right click on element that you want and see the `Id` by inspect element.

Note:

Instead of `clone.querySelectorAll('[id="fieldName"]')[0]` it's better to get element by `querySelector` like `clone.querySelector('[id="fieldName"]')`

Hope will help you.

Comment: I need to increment <tr id="repeat"> also. Also need to assign incremented "name" for the radio buttons.

Comment: Just by `clone.id="repeat"+i;` change the id of `tr` and `clone.children[2].children[0].name` related to name of mandatory radio, See the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works for me. Only one issue with Radio Buttons. My html was <td id="repeat"><input type="radio" id="mandatory" name="mandatory" value="true"/><input type="radio" id="mandatory" name="mandatory" value="false"/></td> When I am trying to clone everythings are fine apart from 2nd radio button is not getting its new id as well as new name.

Comment: @Soma, Sorry I was off for 2 days, which one does not get new `id` or `nam` , mandatory ? did you try that JSFiddle test ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have fixed with the help of your solution.